# modal pop up window to fit within browser view if resize height

Tags: jquery, popup, resize, modal-dialog

I've went to this tutorial to do a modal pop up window, and it seems pretty nice for what I need to do. However, I was wondering if someone can help me figure out what I need to calculate to change the dialog box so it'll follow whenever you resize the browser. This tutorial is good because if you resize the browser (width-wise), the box will follow and go into the middle. But if it is height-wise, it wont.

Tutorial : [Here](http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3)

I'm thinking it has to do with these codes :

```
    // get the screen height and width  
var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

// calculate the values for center alignment
var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height()/3);  
var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 

// assign values to the overlay and dialog box
$('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
$('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();
```

I've tried to use $(window).height() but I don't think that works either. I tried to mimic the width styles because that one works, but it doesn't seem to work with height? Can someone help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tF8TU/2/)**. You can resize the window and try it re positions the dialog box automatically into center.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(window).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight  - $('#dialog-box').height())/2;  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth - $('#dialog-box').width())/2; 

    // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
    $('#dialog-overlay').css({ height:$(document).height(), width:$(document).width() }).show();
    $('#dialog-box').css({ top: dialogTop, left: dialogLeft, position:"fixed"}).show();
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: the problem I'm having is that the popup only shows the window screen resolution, and not the browser window screen. If my page is really long, and it has a link at the bottom. The popup will be half of the window screen (based on the calculation) at the the top of the page. I'm trying to have it popup wherever my current browser view is.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tF8TU/2/ I have modified it now. Also modified my answer.

Comment: Now if you scroll the overlay's height covers the entire document and also the box always stays at the center.

Comment: What about if the content of the modal exceeds the height of the screen?  It then clips off the top and bottom of the box and there is no way to scroll to see the contents.  Take a look at this fiddle...[http://jsfiddle.net/tF8TU/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/tF8TU/3/) for an example of what I mean. Resize to mobile dimensions.  Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: @Adam - In such cases you can resize the modal dialog if the content permits.