# div size of overlays relating to parent size

Tags: html, css, parent

I have a problem with an overlay.

My code is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45ta94xp/9/)

The main problem is in `line 59` of the CSS I think.

```
max-height:auto;
```

If so, the content just flows over the overlay. If I set the `height` to a specific one like

```
max-heigt:250px;
```

everything is fine and the overlay keeps a size and the scrollbar appears. Even set it to 100% doesn't help.

How is it possible to set the size relative to its parent `div`? With `width` it works fine this way, but not for the `height`. I tried with several classes and answers I found here, but either I have to fix the size or the content flows over the overlay. I want to use a relative size so it works with the most desktop resolutions, and don't fix the size. Any solutions that will work?

Comment: I think your jsfiddle is missing some code.. the HTML & JS both look incomplete.

Comment: You've got a body tag that is never closed, plus I would recommend wrapping your non-overlay text in a div, span, p or something.

Comment: Ok, I edited the body mistake. Was only on JSfiddle, not the real code. And the other text is also only for jsfiddle, the correct text is in div of course.

Comment: Ok, so you want the overlay div to fit the text content without scrolling?

Comment: No, the scrolling is ok. Else I could use overflow:hidden or something like that. I only want the child divs, with the content, to fit the size of the overlay. So for a huge text the overlay should use 80% of the page, and the content should fit in it. For small texts the overlay can keep small (works fine).

Comment: So would the font size be changing to fit inside of the overlay? Are the child divs you are referring to the `<p></p>` and the `#OverlayContent` divs? Sorry, I'm still confused as to what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: could you sum up what you are tying to accomplish? for example, "I'd like to make my overlay responsive to the text, regardless of the font-size." That'll make answering your question much easier.

Comment: No, the font size is stable.
As you can see, the content of the overlay flows over the overlay. I don't want that. I want it to be in the box with a scrolling bar. I can achive it by changing the height to a fixed size like 250px. But I don't want to use a fixed size, but a max-height of 80% for the overlay.

Comment: @stuchaet, I think this might be a job for jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143333/modal-pop-up-window-to-fit-within-browser-view-if-resize-height

Comment: Ok. Actually I am not that into jquery yet. Was happy that the overlay works. But I thought it should be possible with div. Especially because it works with the width, but not with height.

Comment: I've played around with this question for almost an hour and I'm pretty sure this simply can't be done with pure CSS. I'm afraid you'll have to look for a javascript solution (such as jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you want but if you specify a specific `height` on both elements it seems to work fine. I suggest you just rename `max-height` to `height`:

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
    ...
    height: 80%;
    ...
}

#OverlayContent {
    ...
    height: calc(100% - 20px); /* subtract padding or use box-sizing */
    ...
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbda9Lwf/)

Comment: forgot about that calc() method, this is a much better solution. I'm going to withdraw my answer since the op didn't want jquery anyway.

Comment: As I wrote before I don't want to use specific sizes. But he calc() method sounds good, I will try it.
And it's not about wanting jQuery, especially because I already use it. I just started to work with jQuery and am not that experienced. But if there is a solution with jQuery it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `.overlay` class will give you a scroll bar and clip the text outside of the container

Comment: Yeah, but then I will have the scrollbar in every overlay. And some are really small, like only 2 or 3 lines, there the scrollbar is just kind of annoying.

Comment: In that case use `overflow-y: auto;`

Comment: You should test your answer before posting it. Neither of these work the way OP wants them to.